# Which word is more proper to be filled in the blank in this sentence，"it" or "he"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

The questioned sentence is:

> In order to find out who _______ might be, they agreed to hang their straw hats up before the door, and he whose hat was blown away was to yield himself up to his fate.

The exact word in the [original article](http://fairytalesandfolklore.com/tale.php?tale=832) is "it", but I am not sure if "he" can also be used.

Which word is more proper to be filled in the blank，"it" or "he"?

Are they both OK here?

Why?

Comment: Sure, both "it" and "he" (and "that person" and etc.) could work there.

Comment: Your example involves a subordinate interrogative clause. Your example could be paraphrase as: *In order to find out the answer to the question "who might it/he be?", they agreed to . . .*

Comment: The reason why the "it" version is possible is because your example involves a truncated it-cleft. Consider: *It might be Tom (that is at the door)* --> (interrogative) *Who might it be (that is at the door)?* --> *Who might it be?* (truncated); and when that interrogative is a subordinate clause (as it is in your example), it becomes: *who it might be*.

Comment: Of course, the "he" version is fine, as the main clause interrogative could be *"Who might he be?"*, and as a subordinate clause, it becomes *"who he might be"*.

Comment: @F.E. Thank you for the answers. But I am still expecting some more solid examples to convince myself of the "he" version.

Comment: In what circumstances do people use "who he might be?" in stead of "who it might be?"

Comment: In your example itself, the word "he" could just as easily be used, as could the NP "the sinner". Consider: *The farmers were greatly frightened, and thought that there must be* **a sinner** *among them, whom the lightning would strike. In order to find out who* ---it--- **the sinner/he** *might be, they agreed to* ...

Comment: If you wait a day or so, someone (else) will probably write an answer post that will explain the grammar behind all this. ("he" will work if we can assume that all the farmers are male--which we can since the story assumes that too, due to *"**he** whose hat was blown away was to yield himself up to **his** fate"*.)

Comment: Usually, in questions similar to this one, the OP would accept "he" but would question the acceptability of "it", for they would reason that you can't use "it" to refer to a farmer. :)

Comment: @F.E. Your explanations do make sense, but what about the problem of gender? Is it acceptable in standard English for people to use "he" while the person's gender is still unknown?

Comment: In your story, it is assumed that the farmers are all male, and that the sinner is one of them; that can be seen in the excerpt: "**he** whose hat was blown away was to yield **himself** up to **his** fate".

Comment: @F.E. If leave the story aside, is it acceptable in standard English for people to use "he" while the person's gender is still unknown? For example，can I say "Someone must have eaten my food, who might he be?"（It might have been eaten by a woman.）

Comment: Er, that's a different type of question, one which could be related to "singular 'they' ". For instance, one possibility, which would use *singular they*, could be: "Someone must have eaten my food. I wonder who they might be?" <-- that's just one possibility. And so, your last question might be more about, er, "style"; it isn't really about grammar per se.

Comment: You could also try to use a truncated it-cleft, such as: *"Someone must have eaten my food. **It** had to be someone working here (who had eaten my food), but who could **it** be (that had eaten my food)?"* <-- notice that there are two it-clefts in that last example.

Answer (score 2):

The correct word is "it" used for identifying or emphasizing that you are referring to a particular person or thing.

I think the pronoun "he" does not fit in this context, which may be used for a specific person such as "I often see this man in the club.  Do you know who he is".

Answer (score 2):

"It" is the correct choice.

When the sentence is read alone, "who he might be" sounds a little like asking for the identity of a pre-specified person, whereas "who it might be" sounds like asking "which person?"

However, interestingly, "he" sounds more acceptable when read in the context of the full story. Because it's a fable, its style and and cadence makes using "he" appear more natural than in the stand-alone sentence.

Comment: It sounds to me that if "he" is used, then the speaker is probably quite sure that a specific person exists there, and knows his gender. If "it" is used, the speaker is not quite sure about if there is any person or whether that person is male or female. I must say I am a little confused.